# How to resample data in data frame without changing one specific column?

Tags: python, pandas, csv, numpy

For instance I have several rows in that I want to resample into 1 second time range, but I need the column ID remains.

```py
time            id   acc   step
00:00:01.2      1    1.2    10
00:00:01.6      1    1.4    20
00:00:01.9      1    1.1    10
```

My current code is only to resample based on each column, and I need help on keeping the "id" column. Thanks!

```py
data = data.resample('1S').agg({'acc': np.mean, 'step': np.sum}).dropna()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe you need add aggregation for `id` column too - e.g. [`Resampler.first`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.resample.Resampler.first.html):

```
data = data.resample('1S').agg({'acc': np.mean, 'step': np.sum, 'id':'first'}).dropna()
```

But if need grouping by `id` with resample:

```
data = data.groupby('id').resample('1S').agg({'acc': np.mean, 'step': np.sum}).dropna()
```

Or solution with [`Grouper`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Grouper.html):

```
data=data.groupby(['id',pd.Grouper(freq='1s')]).agg({'acc': np.mean, 'step': np.sum}).dropna()
```

Comment: Perfect! One more question is: how to round the 'id' into not decimal, e.g. new 'id' column will show '1.0' rather than '1'. Thanks!

Comment: @npm - You can try - `data['step'] = data['step'].astype(int)`